# Can't include js file in wordpress in just one template

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to include the external js file https://checkout.reepay.com/checkout.js in a wordpress template.

In my functions i have this code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'inputtitle_submit_scripts' );

function inputtitle_submit_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'reepay_checkout', 'https://checkout.reepay.com/checkout.js', false );
}
```

But I only want it in one template.

What I do is adding it to all headers.

How should that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'inputtitle_submit_scripts' );

function inputtitle_submit_scripts() 
{
    if (is_page_template('example-template.php'))
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'reepay_checkout', 'https://checkout.reepay.com/checkout.js', false );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an [is_page_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) conditional.

Like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'inputtitle_submit_scripts' );

function inputtitle_submit_scripts() {

    if ( is_page_template('directory-name/your-template-page.php') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'reepay_checkout', 'https://checkout.reepay.com/checkout.js', false );
    }

}
```